# `move || async move {...}`, how to know which move is moving which?

Tags: rust, async-await, concurrency, parallel-processing, move

Consider the following contrived code snippet, pardon that it is kind of 'long':

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread;

pub async fn add_two_num_with_more_number(_: u64, _: &str) {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let many_nums: [u64; 1] = [1];
    let not_copyable: Arc<str> = "foo".into();

    thread::scope(|s| {
        many_nums.iter().for_each(|num| {
            let not_copyable: Arc<str> = Arc::clone(&not_copyable);
            s.spawn(move || async move {
                // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
                add_two_num_with_more_number(*num, &not_copyable).await;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The above codes compile: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2bd4c57c64c92fb44f454e800e61caee).

My question pertains to the line `move || async move {...}`, let's name the first `move` 'move-one' and the second `move`, 'move-two', i.e. `move (move-one) || aync move (move-two) {...}`.

When 'move-two' is removed, the error appears:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0373]: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows `not_copyable`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:14:29
   |
14 |               s.spawn(move || async  {
   |  _____________________________^
15 | |                 // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
16 | |                 add_two_num_with_more_number(*num, &not_copyable).await;
   | |                                                     ------------ `not_copyable` is borrowed here
17 | |             });
   | |_____________^ may outlive borrowed value `not_copyable`
   |
note: async block is returned here
  --> src/main.rs:14:29
   |
14 |               s.spawn(move || async  {
   |  _____________________________^
15 | |                 // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
16 | |                 add_two_num_with_more_number(*num, &not_copyable).await;
17 | |             });
   | |_____________^
help: to force the async block to take ownership of `not_copyable` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
14 |             s.spawn(move || async move  {
   |                                   ++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0373`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error.
```

When 'move-one' is removed, likewise (error shown is for `second` but same for `first`):

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `num`, which is owned by the current function
  --> src/main.rs:14:22
   |
11 |     thread::scope(|s| {
   |                    - lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `s`
...
14 |             s.spawn( || async move {
   |                      ^^ may outlive borrowed value `num`
15 |                 // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
16 |                 add_two_num_with_more_number(*num, &not_copyable).await;
   |                                              ---- `num` is borrowed here
   |
note: function requires argument type to outlive `'1`
  --> src/main.rs:14:13
   |
14 | /             s.spawn( || async move {
15 | |                 // ------ >>>>> LOOK HERE! <<<<<
16 | |                 add_two_num_with_more_number(*num, &not_copyable).await;
17 | |             });
   | |______________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `num` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
   |
14 |             s.spawn( move || async move {
   |                      ++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0373`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Simply put:

1. 'move-one' moves `*num` into the async block.
2. 'move-two' moves `&not_copyable` into the async block.

My question is:

How do we tell which move is moving which variable into which block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. 'move-one' moves `*num` into the async block.
> 2. 'move-two' moves `&not_copyable` into the async block.

This is not complete. Don't assume that just because the compiler gave you one error and not another, that means that that's the *only* problem with a program. In general, once a compiler (for any language, not just Rust) has reported one error, it can't necessarily correctly understand the rest of the program — or it may stop in order to avoid giving you many mostly irrelevant additional errors.

---

The rule that `move` applies is very simple: it is that **every free variable** (captured variable) in the body of a closure expression or async block expression is moved into the closure value or future.

A “free variable” is a variable which is used within the expression, but not defined within it. For example, in the expression

```rust
add_two_num_with_more_number(*num, &not_copyable).await
```

the free variables are `num` and `not_copyable`, because there is no `let` or function parameter defining them within this expression, only somewhere else in the program. Now, in your program the next enclosing thing is

```rust
async move {
    add_two_num_with_more_number(*num, &not_copyable).await;
}
```

This `async` block expression constructs an anonymous `Future` type that executes the call to `add_two_num_with_more_number`. Because it is `async move`, both of its free variables (`num`, `not_copyable`) will be moved into the future, when the async block expression is evaluated.

Outside that, we find:

```rust
move || async move {
    add_two_num_with_more_number(*num, &not_copyable).await;
}
```

Just like with the async block, `move` being on the closure expression means that when the closure expression is evaluated, all of its free variables are moved into the closure value. In this case, no variables were mentioned or bound outside the async block but inside the closure, so the set of free variables is the same (`num`, `not_copyable`) but it doesn't have to be in all cases.

---

If `move` is *not* written, on a closure or on an async block, then a more complex rule is used, where values are borrowed if their *usage within the closure* permits, and moved if not. The point of `move` is to allow you to change that rule when it is undesirable for the closure to borrow things.

Again, compilers do not necessarily tell you *everything* wrong with the program. It just happened that, when you compiled two different variations of the program, the compiler encountered a different one of your two variables which caused it to decide there was a fatal problem.

Because of this sort of thing, I consider it to be wise to avoid having a program that is not compiling while you work on it for a long time — whenever your program does not compile, fix that as directly as you can, before you go on changing the design of the program. If you don't, then you can find yourself in a situation where you thought something was okay because there wasn't any error *there*, but in fact an error the compiler found previously was preventing it from continuing to find additional errors.